# How to use CodeObjectCreateExpression for System.DateTime in C# codeDom

Tags: c#

Here i the method 'BOOL()' returns a Boolean value.
Now i need to do similar thing of returning a DateTime value. When i used,

```
new CodePrimitiveExpression(DATETIME());
```

where 'DATETIME()' returns a DateTime value.
But i got the below exception when i tried CodePrimitiveExpression,

```
Invalid Primitive Type: System.DateTime. Consider using CodeObjectCreateExpression.
```

**So how  can i use CodeObjectExpression to get a DateTime value.?**

Here is the code snippet attached.

```
if (p.ParameterType == typeof(System.Boolean))
                return new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(p.ParameterType, options.sVariableNamePrix + p.Name,
                    new CodePrimitiveExpression(BOOL()));
else if (p.ParameterType == typeof(System.DateTime))
                return new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement(p.ParameterType, options.sVariableNamePrix + p.Name,
                   // new CodeObjectCreateExpression(DATETIME()));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to specify the type of the object (`DateTime` in this case) and the parameter(s) to pass to its constructor.

If you want the generated declaration to use the value returned from your `DATETIME()` method then it's probably easiest to use the `DateTime(long ticks, DateTimeKind kind)` constructor.

```
// ...
else if (p.ParameterType == typeof(System.DateTime))
{
    DateTime dt = DATETIME();

    var ticks = new CodePrimitiveExpression(dt.Ticks);
    var kind = new CodeFieldReferenceExpression
        (
            new CodeTypeReferenceExpression("System.DateTimeKind"),
            dt.Kind.ToString()
        );

    return new CodeVariableDeclarationStatement
        (
            p.ParameterType,
            options.sVariableNamePrix + p.Name,
            new CodeObjectCreateExpression("System.DateTime", ticks, kind)
        );
}
```

**EDIT in response to comment...**

If you want the generated declaration to use the value that was returned from your `DATETIME()` method then that value needs to be passed into the `DateTime` object's constructor somehow.

I chose the [`DateTime(long ticks, DateTimeKind kind)` constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w0d47c9c.aspx) because it's the simplest constructor that allows you to accurately represent that value. (Using [any of the other constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime.aspx) would have made the example either more complicated or less accurate.)

Using [`Ticks`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.ticks.aspx) and [`DateTimeKind`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.kind.aspx) is just a different way to represent the same `DateTime`:

```
DateTime dt1 =
    new DateTime(630822816000000000, System.DateTimeKind.Unspecified);

DateTime dt2 = DateTime.Parse("1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM");

Console.WriteLine(dt1);           // displays "01/01/2000 00:00:00"
Console.WriteLine(dt2);           // displays "01/01/2000 00:00:00"
Console.WriteLine(dt1 == dt2);    // displays "True"
```

Comment: my DATETIME method returns something like this '1/1/2000 12:00:00 AM' which i need to use. Also can u explain what is 'ticks' and 'kind'. When i tried your code i'm getting something like this, '630822816000000000, System.DateTimeKind.Unspecified'